# How to set system property to test Contrast Security Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, security, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to try the Contrast Security Plugin for Eclipse and when I started the server with Contrast  I got the following message when It started up:

`WARNING! Windows users on Java7 may have to set the '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack' system property for Contrast to report issues`

Could someone explain to me what that means and how to set this?

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 will prefer to use IPv6 by default. If that's causing problems for this application you can set that property in the `eclipse.ini` file in the root of your Eclipse installation. At the end of the file it should have `-vmargs`, add it on a new line after this.

```
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack
```